# Azure search action group

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Suppose an action group is used in multiple Alerts. This action group is linked with a Logic App.

How to get a report that in which alerts/azure resources this action group is consumed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `microsoft.insights/metricalerts` and `microsoft.insights/activitylogalerts` to find out which Action Groups are in which Alerts.

Thank you [Billy York](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/152036) and [Juval](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/424832). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

```
Resources
| project
    alertName = name,
    location,
    type,
    props = properties
| where type contains "microsoft.insights/activitylogalerts" 
| mvexpand actionGroups = parse_json(props["actions"]["actionGroups"])
| extend actionGroup = extract(@"([^\/]+$)",1,tostring(actionGroups.actionGroupId))
| union 
    (
        resources
        | project
            alertName = name,
            location,
            type,
            props = properties
        | where type contains "microsoft.insights/metricalerts" 
        | mvexpand actionGroups = parse_json(props["actions"])
        | extend actionGroup = extract(@"([^\/]+$)",1,tostring(actionGroups.actionGroupId))
    )
```

```
az monitor activity-log alert action-group add -n {AlertName} -g {ResourceGroup} \
  --action /subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/{ActionGroup} \
  --webhook-properties usage=test owner=jane
```

You can refer to [Is there a smart way to find out which Action Groups are in which Alerts?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/is-there-a-smart-way-to-find-out-which-action-groups-are-in/m-p/1499250), [az monitor activity-log alert action-group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log/alert/action-group?view=azure-cli-latest) and [How to create an alert rule using PowerShell and Azure CLI](https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-create-an-alert-rule-using-powershell-and-azure-cli/)

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

The following is a [Kusto query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/) that provides alert rules that use a given action group.

```
Resources
| project
    alertName = name,
    enabled = case(properties.enabled == true, true, properties.state == "Enabled", true, false),
    location,
    type,
    props = properties
| where type in (
    "microsoft.insights/metricalerts",
    "microsoft.insights/activitylogalerts",
    "microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartdetectoralertrules",
    "microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules")
| where enabled == 1
| mvexpand actionGroup = extract_all(@'(?i:/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/(?P<actionGroup>.*?)")', tostring(props))
| project alertName, enabled, location, type, actionGroup, props
| where actionGroup =~ "Developers"
| order by ["alertName"] asc
```

**To Use**

Alter the name of the action group in the second to last line, or comment out the line completely to see all rule-to-action-group pairings.

**Caveats**

- There may be other alert rule types than the 4 (common) types in this query.
- We are using an [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operation to expand rules that contain multiple action groups into multiple rows.